# Firing a function when the screen width passes an array of breakpoints with debounce

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am debouncing a window resize function with lodash and want to set it up so when it finishes resizing it calls a function if a user has resized past either above or below one of my breakpoints.

Here's a short example of what I'm trying to do, the array assigned to breakpoints cannot be hardcoded:

```
  this.resizeListener = debounce(() => this.resizeFunc(), 
  250)

  window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener)

  resizeFunc() {

    const breakpoints = [768, 1024, 320];
    if (breakpoints.includes(window.innerWidth)) {
      myFunc()
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm having is because the `resizeFunc` function doesn't actually run until the browser has finished resizing because of the debounce, it's not firing `myFunc` when it should. Is there a way for me to check if window.innerHeight has moved past (either above or below) one of the numbers in my `breakpoints` array so it fires off correctly?

I'm using regular JavaScript, not jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: If at all possible, solve this in CSS with media queries

Comment: @Timo I'm using this to re-fire a JavaScript event so not possible.

Answer (score 1):

With [window#matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) you can use [media queries in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries). You define a css like media query, and you can assign an event handler to notify you when the media query status changes.

Since the event is called only when a breakpoint is passed, you don't need to debounce the event handler.

Demo - click **run code snippet**, then **full page**, and resize the window

**Code:**

```js
const breakpoints = [768, 1024, 320];

const generateMatches = (breakpoints, cb) => breakpoints.map((breakpoint) => {
  const mql = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${breakpoint}px)`); // create a MediaQueryList
  
  // create the listener and return the handler, so it can be canceled
  return mql.addListener((e) => cb(e, breakpoint));
});

const myFunc = (e, breakpoint) => console.log(`${breakpoint}: ${e.matches}`);

const listeners = generateMatches(breakpoints, myFunc);
```